# Accessing functions/variables inside a UITabBarController with or without global variables?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

currently I have a layout like this with my app. I have a UITabBarcontroller as my root view controller inside app delegate, this is fine and works great.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = Tabs()


    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.init(r: 198, g: 214, b: 91)
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.init(r: 47, g: 47, b: 47)




    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.init(r: 53, g: 57, b: 77)


    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.init(r: 198, g: 214, b: 91)
```

However, in my layout with the tab controller, I have laid it out in a way where i have UITabBar at the top, followed by an override didload function that lays out all the views like this.

```
 class Tabs: UITabBarController{


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    tabBar.isTranslucent = true


    let feed = feedController()
    let feedArray = UINavigationController(rootViewController: feed)
    let feedButton = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "feed.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedimage.png"))
    feedButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    feedArray.tabBarItem = feedButton



    let messages = messagesController()
    let messagesArray = UINavigationController(rootViewController: messages)
    let messagesButton = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "messages.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedimage.png"))
    messagesButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    messagesArray.tabBarItem = messagesButton


    let post = postController()
    let postButton = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "post.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedimage.png"))
    postButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    post.tabBarItem = postButton


    let profile = profileController()


    let profileArray = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profile)
    let profileButton = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "profile.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedimage.png"))

    profileButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    profile.tabBarItem = profileButton






    let settings = settingsController()
    let settingsArray = UINavigationController(rootViewController: settings)
    let settingsButton = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "settings.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedimage.png"))
    settingsButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    settingsArray.tabBarItem = settingsButton





    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {


            self.handleLogout()}
    }


/* all views BOII */    viewControllers = [feedArray, messagesArray, post, profileArray, settingsArray]
```

However, when I try to access a function or whatever in a viewcontroller inside this tab controller from another viewcontroller inside.  like this

```
class settingsController: UIViewController{ 

messagesController().removeMessages()

}
```

.......

```
class messagesController: UIViewController{
    removeMessages(){
            messages.removeAll()
            messagesDictionary.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()


            print("working")

}
}
```

The functions get called (im putting it in a function on logout), I get the print message but anything I wanted affected on that viewcontroller does not seem to work. Currently, I have so far tried these methods (on settings controller).

I know this has to do with something with a tabbarcontroller in swift, something about how the views inside run parallel to each other.

What I did do and it worked, was put the declarations of the variables before the class in my tabs.swift file. So I took the let statements that set up the views and put them before the class was declared and under the import statements. This worked, but is this bad practice and is there a better way of doing it? As this let statements are now global.

Really would appreciate the help guys and Im so sorry for the long post, I just wanted you to try and understand what Im saying here, I'm new.

Comment: Try to open every tab before. Maybe your view controllers not loaded yet.

Comment: If it all viewDidLoad methods run before than it indicates that you call that methods not in main thread.

Comment: @ObranS tried that mate, it's something to do with it being declared, like I can fix it by having them let statements as globals (declaring them outside the class), but I'm not sure if that is bad practice, for security and what not. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Hmmm, I see @ObranS. What would you suggest to do?

Comment: You have a couple options... 1) use your custom TabBarController as a "message router" - that is, SettingsController tells TabBar to tell MessagesController.removeMessages(), or 2) Use the Delegate pattern.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks mate, I just want to ask you, how do I go about doing these :D . And what would be best do you think from your personal experience.

Comment: see below answer. I think this is the reason

Comment: As for me you should separate logic and UI. When you call removeMessages you should manage it form manager or some service not from ViewController

Comment: Think about ViewController like a display only class

Comment: @zak - kinda complex for a single answer... I recommend reading up on delegate patterns. This article looks like it might be a decent read for you (I have no association with it - just found it via a quick search): https://makeapppie.com/2015/02/04/swift-swift-tutorials-passing-data-in-tab-bar-controllers/

Comment: @DonMag thanks mate, I'll have a look. I think I had a look at this earlier actually. Anything else you have or suggesting me, let me know right away. Thanks again mate :)

Answer (score 0):

If your UIKit objects manipulates from current stack it won't work. Since object should be called from main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.handleLogout()
}
```

I can only suggest you fast solution use next block for UI elements:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    messages.removeAll()
    messagesDictionary.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I am trying to do mate, but you fixed another bug for me, thanks! :)

Comment: Its just the fact that I can never access functions or variables when I have two controllers embedded in a UITabBarController, and this is what I am trying to get at. Even though I have listed one problem here, its affecting the app im trying to build because I need to share functions between the viewcontrollers but I am struggling too do that because of this tabbarcontroller.